# Render JavaScript inside a <code> tag with JSX

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I am using React to render some UI components. I would like to display some JavaScript code inside of `<code>` tag. I've tried the following:

```
class A extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <pre><code>
                (function(a, b) {
                    var s = a.prop;
                    // ...
                }(c, d));
            </code></pre>
        );
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this script with webpack and Babel, I get an unexpected token error at the line `var s = a.prop`. How can I properly render this JavaScript?

Comment: you want to return a string, yet nothing is in quotes...

Comment: The above code is written in JSX syntax. What is being returned is a React element. The code to generate the React element is automatically generated by the JSX transpiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Pamblam is right, you quite literally need a string:

```
  render() {
    var foo = `
      (function(a, b) {
        var s = a.prop;
        // ...
      }(c, d));
    `

    return (
      <pre>
        <code>{foo}</code>
      </pre>
    )
  }
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/41974/)**

Comment: You can use `{\` ... \`}` to escape a multi-line string inside JSX.

Comment: @Aaron that's what I tried first and it didn't work. I just went back and tried again and it did. hmm. I thought the IIFE in the string was some edge case for brackets strings in jsx