# Format JSON string to render in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm trying to print a json string in a json format.

So, the input would be something like: `"{\"a": 1, \"b\":\"2\"}"`

I need the output to look like this:

```
{
  "a":1,
  "b":"2"
}
```

I have tried using JSON.stringify but it just prints out the same string. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the different? `\` is an escape char.

Comment: JSON is only ever a string. Other than not having a space between `"a":` and `1` (yeah... don't), you *could* parse to a JavaScript object, then stringify and give it a parameter to tell it to indent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: While re-reading the question, I figured that [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4810841/1218980) would fit more than the one I suggested above.

Comment: And to render pre-formatted code, you might want to look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37213957/1218980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse your string to js object, than parse it to string to with new lines.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('{\"a": 1, \"b\":\"2\"}'), null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Before just running below code you should make a small change.

```
"{\"a": 1, \"b\":\"2\"}" ->
"{\"a\": 1, \"b\":\"2\"}"

const stringifiedJson = "{\"a\": 1, \"b\":\"2\"}";
const result = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(result);
```